# Why do we use similarities between two items in clustering?

Tags: r, clustering

In some clustering algorithms , we use as an input similarities measures or distance between each two elements (similarities matrix). I am wondering why can't we use similarities between 3, 4 or more elements ? Why they are always taken 2 by 2 ?

Comment: Interesting question.  The fact is that you *can*: I did it some 20 years ago when studying agricultural land allocation in the Netherlands.  But such applications appear to be unusual and require highly specialized procedures because their constraints and objectives can be highly varied.

Comment: Not 2 by 2, but 1 by 1.

Answer (score 2):

How would you define similarity between more than two items? How would you store them? How much memory does it need & how long does it take you to compute it?

Most likely, you will come up with a definition based on 2-item comparisons... for example, Hausdorff distance.

And in fact, if you do hierarchical clustering, you *begin* with 2-item comparisons, but as you merge clusters, you get 2-vs-1 comparisons next, and then n-vs-m comparisons.

Comment: Thank you but i am not really convinced. why do don't they begin with a comparison of 3 or 4 or more items. Did they choose comparisons in pairs only for simplification reasons ?

Comment: Which 3 or 4 items? There are n-choose-4 options, that is too many to try. That would be a n-by-n-by-n-by-n tensor.

Comment: And as mentioned above, name or define a measure that is not based on pairwise computations. You'll notice that it is not easy to even come up with something that doesn't have this property.